# Can't figure out why client inputs still appear after submission and Model Validation between a plain ActionResult and a separate POST ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I was previously doing my views without `[HttpPost]` in this manner:

```
public ActionResult Details(string nextButton)
{
    if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
    return View(myData);
}
```

**NB:** `myData` is my serialized View Model (which I am not sure if this is the problem).

I also was previously using DataAnnotations on my properties, e.g. `[Required]`. If any fields in the `.cshtml` view failed to validate (i.e., no input in a required text box), upon clicking the "nextButton", the user would be presented with the standard client-side validation error (as well as previous items filled in would still be filled in).

If the user corrected the errors and went through to submit the information they could re-visit that page later and it would be blank (i.e., none of their prior inputs would be visible if they submitted).

Now, in order to localize text I've had to move away from `DataAnnotations` and put validation in my controller temporarily. So I have also started using `[HttpPost]` thusly:

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    return View(myData);
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Details")]
public ActionResult DetailsPOST(string nextButton)
{
    if (DetailsValidation())
    {
        if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
    }
    return View(myData);
}
    ...
private bool DetailsValidation()
{
    bool validate = true;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myData.FirstName))
    {
        AddModelError("FirstName", T("Please specify a First Name."));
        validate = false;
    }

    if (!validate)
    return false;

    if (myData.FirstName.Length > 25)
    {
        AddModelError("FirstName", 
            T("First Name cannot be more than 25 letters."));
    }

    return ModelState.IsValid;
}
```

The above code works with my validations all the way to submission. However, the problem now is if the user returns to the Details view the data they entered populates the text boxes, whereas with the original way (no `[HttpPost]` or special validation) if the user went back to the Details view they would be presented with a fresh page (none of their data in the text boxes).

Sorry if this isn't clear. But is there a way to have the text boxes clear after submission, so if the user goes back its a fresh page? Or is this just something I have to deal with given the new way I am doing things.

Thanks.

**UPDATE** How I created `myData` in the Controller:

```
private MyViewModel myData;
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var serialized = Request.Form["myData"];
    if (serialized != null) //Form was posted containing serialized data
    {
        myData = (MyViewModel)new MvcSerializer()
            .Deserialize(serialized, SerializationMode.Signed);
            TryUpdateModel(myUsData);
    }
    else
        myData = (MyViewModel)TempData["myData"] ?? new MyViewModel();
        TempData.Keep();
}
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
        TempData["myData"] = myData;
}
```

I use this for a wizard, to pass data to a subsequent view (Details > Confirm > Submit).

Comment: How are you populating `myData` in your get `Details` action method?

Comment: @WannaCSharp Updated code to show how `myData` is handled.

Answer (score 0):

How did you initialize `myData` in this action method? Did you populate it with the data from the database?

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    return View(myData);
}
```

If so, you could initialize an empty myData and pass it to your view:

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    var myData = new UserData();
    return View(myData);
}
```

Comment: Updated code to show how `myData` is handled. I think newing up `myData` will create problems. I am serializing a View Model in order to have steps in a wizard (Details > Confirm > Submit).

Answer (score 0):

No real resolution on this issue, so it seems I just have to accept this behavior.